# Haskell IO program that calculates mean and highest value

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

I have doubts to do this exercise. I have the solution (which is apparently wrong) but I could not understand:

Write a program that reads integers from the default input device, one per line, to a negative or zero universe, and prints an average and the largest of the read values.

My code:

```
a6 ::Int -> Float ->Int->Int-> IO()
a6 cBigger average2 sum2 cCount = do
 c <- getLine
 let digit = read c :: Int
 let sum = sum2 + digit
 let average = fromIntegral sum2/ fromIntegral cCount
 if (digit <=0)
     then putStrLn("Bigger :" ++show(cBigger)++ "average "++show(cAverage))
     else
     if digit > cBigger
          then a6 digit average sum (cCount+1)
           else a6 cBigger average sum (cCount+1)
```

As I do not understand much Haskell I have doubts of how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a little off topic, I thought I would comment on separation of concerns and modularity.

Usually, we try to keep the pure parts of the program separate from the impure (`IO`) parts.

We can read a list of `Int`s with impure code, and then process it with a pure function to find the max, sum, and length in order to compute the average.

Below, `readInts` reads `Int`s from stdin until it reads a non-positive value, returning the positive `Int`s in a list (in `IO`).  `maxSumLength` takes the current maximum, sum, and length of the elements processed so far
as a tuple, and the next element to process, and returns a new tuple with the next element folded in.  Finally, `main` reads the list of `Int`s, and applies a strict left fold (`foldl'`) using `maxSumLength` and an initial state of `(0, 0, 0)` to compute the final maximum, sum, and length.   It then prints the maximum and the average from the sum and length.

```
module Main where

import Data.List ( foldl' )

readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = do
  i <- read <$> getLine
  if i <= 0
    then return []
    else (i:) <$> readInts

maxSumLength :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
maxSumLength (m, s, l) x = (max m x, s+x, l+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (m, s, l) <- foldl' maxSumLength (0, 0, 0) <$> readInts
  putStrLn $ "max=" ++ show m ++ ", avg=" ++ show (fromIntegral s / fromIntegral l)
```

This code is more modular than before.  We could reuse `readInts` in other programs that need a list of `Int`s.  Also, the pure part of the algorithm no longer cares where the list of `Int`s comes from.  However, there is a problem with this code.  When written this way, the entire list has to be buffered in memory before the pure code can start processing it, even though the processing code can consume the input as it arrives.

This is where the `conduit` package can help.  The `conduit` package allows a stream to be produced by an impure `Source` and connected to a pure `Consumer`, and allows the pure code to be interleaved with the impure code.  The `conduit-combinators` package provides combinators that allow streams to be treated much like lists (in particular, `foldlC` allows us to perform a strict left fold over a conduit stream instead of a list).

In the code below, the `readInts` function is now a `Source` of `Int`s that runs in the `IO` monad.  It uses the `repeatWhileMC` combinator to perform the looping and the termination test.  The pure `maxSumLength` is unchanged; however, in `main`, rather than use `foldl'`, we use `foldlC` to fold over the conduit stream.

```
module Main where

import Conduit

readInts :: Source IO Int
readInts = repeatWhileMC (read <$> getLine) (> 0)

maxSumLength :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
maxSumLength (m, s, l) x = (max m x, s+x, l+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (m, s, n) <- runConduit (readInts =$= foldlC maxSumLength (0, 0, 0))
  putStrLn $ "max=" ++ show m ++ ", avg=" ++ show (fromIntegral s / fromIntegral n)
```

This code will interleave pure `maxSumLength` with the impure `readInts` so that the `Int`s are consumed as they are created, but without sacrificing modularity.  The `readInts` stream can be used in other programs that need a stream of `Int`s, and the pure code still no longer cares where the `Int`s are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

While not optimal, your program is almost working. Here's some minor fixes and cleanups. I tried to keep your original code when possible, even if there might be better solutions.

First, you are using `cAverage` which is not defined. This error can be easily fixed.

The `average2` parameter is pointless, since it is unused -- let's remove it.

Some `let`s can be moved to the branches where we actually use those variables.

We can also perform a minor refactoring and compute the new `bigger` value using a conditional, instead of using a conditional to perform two different recursive calls. (It would be even better to use the `max` function, though.)

Consider to rename "bigger" to "biggest", or "greatest", or "maximum". It sounds better to me.

```
a6 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO()
a6 bigger oldSum count = do
 c <- getLine
 let digit = read c :: Int
 if digit <= 0
     then let average = fromIntegral oldSum / fromIntegral count :: Double
          in putStrLn ("Bigger: " ++ show bigger ++ ", average: " ++ show average)
     else let newBigger = if digit > bigger then digit else bigger
              newSum = oldSum + digit
          in a6 newBigger newSum (count+1)
```